# Difference (if any) between 'ponder' and 'contemplate'?

Tags: difference

Is there any difference in connotation between 'ponder' and 'contemplate'?

Put another way, do these two sentences give you exactly the same impression?

> 1. Every day I **ponder** how I should live my life.
> 2. Every day I **contemplate** how I should live my life.

Comment: Related question:  [Some words which mean “thinking over something deeply or for a long time”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/41227)

Comment: I recommend that you include your own research so that answers may supplement what you already know. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for tips and examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is **Is there any difference in connotation between 'ponder' and 'contemplate'?**

Although the meaning is the same, the answer to "Is there any difference in connotation", the answer is it depends what nationality you are. **In the UK the answer would be Yes** (disregarding the persistent degradation of UK English by/of globalisation).  **In UK English Ponder is Formal** whilst in US English it is not. Therefore I would suggest that normally you would not use Ponder in your sentence if using British English.[Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ponder)

Example

> The first issue is **to ponder whether it would be regarded as 'evidence'** at all?
>
> **formal** adjective (SERIOUS)Formal language, clothes, and behaviour are **suitable for serious or official occasions**:[Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/formal)

Comment: Interesting +1. Actually this question has been a same question I wanted to ask for a long time ( jut forgot ).

Comment: I disagree that "ponder" is not formal in US English. I'm also not sure that this is a difference in connotation.

Comment: @Em You may well be correct. I do not propose myself as an expert in US English. However that is what my dictionary seems to think. if you are correct then there is a difference in connotation in both UK & US English, as neither would ponder its use it informally.

Comment: The other day I was talking to a friend and he suggested ‘ponder’ sounds more like wondering over something that doesn’t have a clear answer to, something difficult to find a solution to, whereas ‘contemplate’ is constructing an actual process step by step carefully to find an answer or a solution over something solvable/feasible ... what do you think?

Comment: @Irene basically I agree however the conclusion makes a lot of difference. I would presume Steven Hawkins often sat pondering upon some issue. That would become a subject of some paper after further contemplation.  Here as, often, I am just the messenger for the Dictionaries not the master of the pen.

Comment: @Brad  I think the Steven Hawkins example is a good example of using both 'ponder' and 'contemplate' ... There seems to be a subtle difference in nuance. Thank you for your input, I really appreciate it!